# Stopping bitcoind on mac

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

One of my kids while learning more about bitcoin started bitcoind on my mac. Now I am unable to stop it. In my activity monitor, it shows a process named "bitcoind". I have stopped that process from the activity monitor various times but that doesn't help. It starts again after some time or in the next boot session. It has been taking a lot of my laptop space (>100gb). I am running low on space and I need to stop it now. This has been happening regularly. As a temporary solution, I used to go to /Users/[name]/Library/Application Support/ and delete the "Bitcoin" folder from there. But that's no proper solution to end it completely. I have tried a bunch of stuff using bitcoin-cli in the terminal. However, I am unable to stop it.

Running
`bitcoin-cli stop` returns `error: couldn't connect to server: unknown (code -1) (make sure server is running and you are connecting to the correct RPC port)`.

Can someone please tell me what should I do to stop the bitcoind?

Comment: If you do `ps` in the command line do you see a bitcoind process? If you don't there isn't a bitcoind process running. If you do, does it say testnet next to it?

Comment: Regardless once you do `ps` you can get the process PID number and then do `kill insert_PID_here` replacing insert_PID_here with the PID number of the bitcoind process

Comment: bitcoin is unstoppable XD

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have a relevant setting in one of these

- Start up app at `System Preferences / Users & Groups / Login Items`
- Config file at `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`
- A `bitcoind -daemon` in `~/.bash_profile`

You could run `ps aux | grep bitcoind` to check where it is executing from and then delete that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could open up the Terminal and run `pkill bitcoind`, it should kill it if it is still running.